# Cannot find the hive-hwi-<version>.war file

Tags: java, hadoop, ant, hive, hadoop-yarn

I cannot start Hive Web interface as described [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveWebInterface). This is the output of `hive --service hwi`:

```
ls: cannot access /usr/local/hive/lib/hive-hwi-*.war: No such file or directory
14/09/09 13:07:59 INFO hwi.HWIServer: HWI is starting up
14/09/09 13:08:00 FATAL hwi.HWIServer: HWI WAR file not found at /usr/local/hive/lib/hive-hwi-0.13.1.war
```

It appears that there is no .war file under /usr/local/hive/lib!!! am I supposed to generate the war file?

I've correctly set $ANT_LIB and $HIVE_HOME, and here is my hive-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name>
    <value>hdfs://hadoop-server/user/hive/warehouse</value>
    <description>location of default database for the warehouse</description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.hwi.war.file</name>
    <value>/lib/hive-hwi-0.13.1.war</value>
    <description>This is the WAR file with the jsp content for Hive Web Interface</description>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

My hive version is 0.13.1, and hadoop version is 2.5.0.

Answer (score 0):

There is [HIVE-7233](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-7233)

you may need to change the version of hive or copy war file of another version

Comment: yeah i had to copy it from an older version